# Why InputStream is used over network connection, but not ByteArray?

Tags: java, inputstream

I have following question.

I understand why is InputStream is used when we are working with files or some external sources. 
But what is a point using stream when we are working with network connections?

Say a POST-request with attachment is sent to some application server (Tomcat or other), attachment is sent, so JVM already holds it in memory.

So what is the point using InputStream, but not ByteArray?

Data is in memory already, so to JVM converting InputStream to ByteArray should not take any effect.

Because I think is reasonable when InputStream is used for external sources like files, but not when data is read from memory.

**UPDATE**:

I'm talking about sending attachment via multipart form and attachment is being sent in many packages, but all packages are sent even if I will not read input stream.

Comment: Why do you think the data is already in memory?

Comment: @biziclop because when I'm sending attachment via mutlipart form, then http-post request is multipart request containing whole attachment which is received by Tomcat.

Comment: Sorry, I must be missing something, but I don't see how that guarantees the data is in memory. If I upload a 4GB file, you probably don't want to hold it in memory anyway, you stream it straight to disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong when you said

> Data is in memory already, so to JVM converting InputStream to ByteArray should not take any effect.

Not all the data is  necessarily "in memory already", it is entering the memory as a stream of bytes. You can process the bytes while they arrive (and not keep them in memory, except for a possible buffer).

Same when you write. You push bytes over the stream towards the sink (e.g, a browser). You probably again do so in chunks using a buffer. Only the contents of the buffer is in memory. On every flush those bytes are send over the stream and the buffer is again "empty", ready to be filled up for the next chunk of bytes.

It is really all about pipes and water (hence the jargon *stream*, *flush*,  *sink*)

p.s. you also might want to look into reactive streams where handling of data inflow/outflow is handled by the whole system of pipes (so you never overload a part in the system).

Answer (score 3):

`InputStream` is used because network traffic comes in packets (or other bits of data) it is not fully available from the start - it is NOT fully in the memory for sure (imagine a youtube video that is streaming). So it is a stream and it is treated like that in java.

Comment: I'm sending attachment via http-post request. When sending attachment via multipart form WHOLE attachment is being sent to server! It is being sent by many packets, that's true, but all packets are sent! I haven't decided yet will I read InputStream with attachment, but I've already received it and Tomcat holds them.

Comment: A sent packet does not arrive instantly, and all packets within the same transfer will not arrive at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I run a Tomcat on my machine, and you make a request to it from your machine, even if the data is in memory in my machine, I cannot imagine a way other than a stream over the network to pass the data from one machine to the other. You can send request to my Tomcat, but you cannot directly access memory on my machine.

Even if both programs run on same machine, they are likely to be run on different JVMs and again a JVM cannot directly access memory from another JVM.